# Laravel: Compare two dates against today with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So I have events table which has start date and end date.

What I want to do is a comparison between today and start date + end date so if today is between start and end, return that collection which will be displayed on page, if it isn't ignore that event.

Problem is that when I retrieve an event I cannot access it as it is return that it doesn't exist in the collection, but it does after view is returned.

Here's my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $today_dt = new DateTime($today);
    $event = Event::with('businesses')
        ->get();
    $test = $event->startdate;
    $test2 = $event->enddate;
    //something like if $today is not less that start date and not higher than end date, return that collection?
    dd($test);
    return view('events.showEvent', compact('event'));
}
```

Comment: What column type are you using to store your dates?

Answer (score 1):

use where date function like this

```
$today = Carbon::now();
$event = Event::with('businesses')
           ->whereDate('startdate', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
           ->whereDate('enddate', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, I think this should suffice:

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$event = Event::whereDate('startdate', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->whereDate('enddate', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->with('businesses')
    ->get();
```

I hope you did search the internet for this problem in the first place

Comment: unfortunately this brings me back 0 results :(

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas You can debug by testing what returns when you do only,  `Event::where('startdate', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->where('enddate', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))->get();` Look into your database and see a record you think should be returned, you can replace the `$today` to be your preferred date like: `$today = Carbon::parse('22-01-2017');` for test purpose

Comment: @ShahzaibSheikh how do you mean? You mean putting `$today->format('Y-m-d')` in single quotes? Actually the format() method of Carbon resolves to string at least with little I have seen it do, or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: `whereDate('start', '<', $today->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->whereDate('end', '>', $today->format('Y-m-d'))->get()`use like this

Answer (score 0):

in Model

```
public function scopeOfToday($query){
    $today = \Carbon\Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d');
    return $query->whereRaw("? BETWEEN startdate and enddate",$today);
}
```

in Controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $event = Event::ofToday()->with('businesses')->get();

    $test = $event->startdate;
    $test2 = $event->enddate;
    //something like if $today is not less that start date and not higher than end date, return that collection?
    dd($test);
    return view('events.showEvent', compact('event'));
}
```

Comment: I get that it doesn't exist in current collection

Comment: which one doesn't exist?